# Rendering the output of action in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there some way to output an action in Rails template? Something equivalent to ASP.NET MVC Html.RenderAction ?
I need to render some stuff in sidebar and I don't want to put queries in partials or specific controller. So far I can think of only one way - put something into @stuff (by whatever means) instance var and let render find the proper partial or specify it explicitly. It would be better to be able to change only one file to change the contents of sidebar (as in ASP).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can add the "sidebar" partial to the application layout (in the app/views/layouts folder).

You can put the code that gets the "sidebar" variables in a before_filter in the ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :sidebar_function
```

Comment: Thanx. Forgot I could alter the get_the_stuff filter in controller and let my own helper decide what partial to render. But still, if I want to have each action in controller to have a different sidebar I need to use ":only".

Comment: Or you can use :content_for in your controller's template http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title (Still, don't forget to include reasonable defaults in ApplicationController)

Comment: I guess this is as railish as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

especially read the subitem

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for

Answer (score 0):

I do not know ASP.net, however, I think Rails yield might be the solution. Here is a small example:

view:

```
<% content_for :one do %>
  Test one
<% end %>

<% content_for :two do %>
  Test two
<% end %>

<p>Hi</p>
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= yield :one %>
<%= yield %>
<%= yield :two %>
```

See Railsguides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Comment: Obviously the problem is with dynamic content, that's why I talked about queries and instance vars.

Comment: I do not really see your problem. You either define content_for in your views to let it render in application.html.erb (where I assume your sidebar is) OR define some kind of variables in your controller using a before_filter or doing it in individual controller methods.